# CASE in WHERE clause with array

Tags: sql, oracle

In my program the user has 4 options, "ALL","FK","FK2","FK3". The below code does not work because of the Array.

```
WHERE 
    JOBOP.CC_CODE in 
        CASE :P4_MACHINES 
            WHEN 'ALL' THEN ('FK','FK2','FK3') 
            ELSE :P4_MACHINES 
        END
```

Can someone help me form this clause properly or tell me if it is not possible please?

Just to reiterate my goal in other terms,

```
IF :P4_MACHINES = 'ALL' THEN
    JOBOP.CC_CODE in ('FK','FK2','FK3')
ELSE
    JOBOP.CC_CODE = P4_MACHINES
END
```

Comment: I swear I saw this exact question s couple hours ago.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've been looking at variations of this question for hours but none have an array in the where clause.

Comment: `CASE` is largely provided to allow for Boolean logic where Boolean logic is not normally permitted. Since the `WHERE` clause is inherently a Boolean construct, an attempt to use `CASE` in the `WHERE` clause is almost always misguided (as is suggested by the existing answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm . . . Is this what you want?

```
where (:P4_MACHINES = 'ALL' and  JOBOP.CC_CODE in ('FK','FK2','FK3'))
                             or (JOBOP.CC_CODE = :P4_MACHINES)
```

Comment: @Baonerges - is `JOBOP.CC_CODE` also guaranteed to always be in `('FK', 'FK2', 'FK3')` (and, in particular, to be NOT NULL)? If so, then Gordon's solution should work; otherwise you will need to add `and JOBOP.CC_CODE in ('FK', 'FK2', 'FK3')` before the word `or`.

Comment: I do not think this solution will work. `JOBOP.CC_CODE` can be many other things besides the three options. I can program the button to be `NOT NULL` all the time.

ALL is equivalent to ('FK', 'FK2', 'FK3') so I need to select all three of those if the user selects "ALL' otherwise, I select the specific item the user chose.

Comment: @Baonerges - the solution WILL work with the modification I suggested in my first comment, and you don't need to worry about NULL in that case. NULL is not IN [whatever].

Comment: @Baonerges give it a try :)   this where clause do exactly what you describe with your pseudo code

Comment: @schurik - no, it does not. What if the bind variable is 'ALL' but the CC_CODE is 'FK8'? The OP said the bind variable can be one of only four values; he didn't say anything about CC_CODE being limited that way.

Comment: This does work. If I want any other values to be members of "ALL", I simply will add them to `JOBOP.CC_CODE in ('FK','FK2','FK3')`. So if all is selected AND JOBOP.CC_CODE has the following members, it effectively represents the ones I want to include. Thank you all! The best solutions are simple ones.

Comment: @mathguy . . . Thank you for the edit.  Given the OP's most recent comment, I don't think the change is necessary, but whatever.

Comment: The change IS necessary. The OP is talking about adding to the values the user may choose in the drop-down (the possible values of the bind variables); for all we know, the stored CC_CODE may have 90 different values in the base table even now, but he is singling out FK, FK2, FK3. If in the future he wants to single out FK8 as well, he can easily adapt your solution.

Answer (score 6):

Based on your question update, you can try this:

```
where ( (:P4_MACHINES = 'ALL' AND JOBOP.CC_CODE in ('FK','FK2','FK3'))
       OR JOBOP.CC_CODE = :P4_MACHINES )
```

I may be missing a few brackets since I do not have the entire query.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE 1 = CASE 
    WHEN :P4_MACHINES = 'ALL' THEN CASE WHEN JOBOP.CC_CODE IN ('FK','FK2','FK3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ELSE CASE WHEN JOBOP.CC_CODE = :P4_MACHINES THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
END
```

Comment: Please format code as code by including four spaces at the beginning of every line. Also, please add some explanation -- tell us how this answers the question.